# Conditionally naming cc_binary targets in Bazel

Tags: bazel

We would like to call the 32 bit build of the application "myapp32" and the 64 bit build as "myapp64" and they would be put in the same directory when shipping.

Currently I have two identical targets whose only difference is the name and they look sort of like this:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "myapp32",
    srcs = MYAPP_SRCS,
    copts = MYAPP_COPTS,
    deps = MYAPP_DEPS
)

cc_binary(
    name = "myapp64",
    srcs = MYAPP_SRCS,
    copts = MYAPP_COPTS,
    deps = MYAPP_DEPS
)
```

Then another rule conditionally picks the appropriate one using select() to get it built.

During build the program is built using the 32 bit configuration then the 64 bit one, which gives us both the executables.

Is it possible to avoid this kind of duplication somehow?

I tried:

- Using select() in the name, but Bazel does not accept that. It only accepts a string as name.
- Renaming the executable after the fact. But then the debugger would look for .pdb files with unchanged filename. So we cannot put both .pdbs into the same directory (identical name).